# Under which title in CV should I list a paper accepted in a conference?

Tags: publications, conference, cv

I had sent a paper for a conference and it was accepted recently. I am wondering under which title I should mention it in my CV? Since it will be published in April so I can't use the title "publication", so which title should I use?

Comment: For papers that have been accepted but have not yet appeared, it is common to list them under "publications" with the note "in press".

Comment: Just for the record, the same can't be done to submitted papers that were not yet accepted. I'm aware that this is not the OP's situation, but I've seen CVs with a "submitted works" section...

Comment: Don't undersell yourself. Most people will not care about the distinction between accepted for publication in the future and accepted for publication in the past. Put it in post-scripted "[accepted]" and if anyone in your interview asks you what that means, you can waffle for a few minutes about it so they have less time to ask you difficult questions.

Answer (score 11):

For papers that have been accepted, but not yet published, it is common to mention them as "accepted for publication". This is similar for journals and conferences.

So in your case, you could mention the paper under a section titled "accepted for publication", or you could add this information at the end of the paper entry:

> - author name, paper title, conference name, year (accepted for publication).

Another option is, as mentioned by @David Ketcheson, to list such papers as "in press".

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't even bother to make the distinction: The paper is in, the conference date is known--especially if you make it a habit to list the month and year. List it the exact same way as if the conference had been two months ago.

Comment: Agreed, if you know the date, just put it.  I think everyone will understand what is meant by a paper whose publication date is six months down the road.