# Would acceptance letters from conferences be good in my CV?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, cv, medicine

I graduated and I am trying to build my CV in order to apply for a master's scholarship. I wrote articles in my field, but since I am a fresh grad and I wrote them with no other authors, they haven't been accepted by journals. I sent them to conferences and they got accepted by multiple conferences, however, I can't afford to attend any of them.

**Should I add the acceptance letters from conferences to my CV?**
For context, I am in the medical field.

Comment: Hi lia, welcome to Ac.SE. I removed your second question because we have a one-question-per-question policy. I think other questions like that one  have been asked on this site before, I encourage you to look for them.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the conferences about a reduced or free admission? Sometimes they have the possibility to do that for people without funds and it never hurts to ask.

Comment: related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63185/under-which-title-in-cv-should-i-list-a-paper-accepted-in-a-conference

Comment: related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/how-submitted-to-appear-accepted-papers-are-evaluated-in-a-cv

Comment: Why submit your research to conferences/journals if you know in advance you are not going to go through with presentation/publishing? That way you are wasting reviewers' time. Hoping for a reduced/free admission or seeking funding to cover travel/living expenses is fair game, but if you are not even trying to obtain it, that strikes me as unethical. Not an enormous offense, but still...

Comment: Hi Lodinn, thanks for your nice comment. Anyways.. I am from a developing country that is currently suffering an economical crisis , so yes I thought that conference acceptance letters are strong for my cv and no I can't afford to go because its hella expensive and i am not 'funded' by any organization

Comment: Going to a conference might've helped. Acceptance letters don't really move the needle. Unfortunately for you, recruiters in developed countries can afford to be picky, but you can't afford major risks such as moving to other country without a job offer laid out. Realistically, I'd advise to aim a bit lower and improve your immediate situation for now and build your profile. Desperation would likely lead to either blacklisting or giving you a job offer with slave-like working conditions. Not just "work really hard" ones. The bad ones. Especially given the field.

Comment: I wish I had something more positive to say, but ultimately, the upcoming years are going to be enormously important to you, and unless you already hit the rock bottom and are willing to work for food doing whatever odd job comes up, you still have something to lose and will need to measure your next steps carefully. Maybe try to find a place with a bit less fierce competition where you would have some advantage: be it knowing local language/customs, having a support network, or something else. Aiming straight at a spot in a hyper-competitive environment is hoping for a miracle.

Answer (score 1):

Will the conference publish abstracts of the accepted papers, or possibly a journal in the field may have a section where the abstracts are published, hardcopy or online?  This might be citeable, but I don’t think a letter of acceptance is acceptable because what goes in a CV is work others saw or can find. A letter of acceptance by itself makes none of your work public, even the abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Being accepted to a conference isn't necessarily a sign of renown/quality work. Therefore, I wouldn't advise attaching them to your CV. In your situation, it'd be best to have some joint publications or, perhaps, ask a colleague attending the conference to inquire if the conference will publish them anywhere (online or offline.)

I'd also advise you take a look at some journals that are, perhaps, less prestigious but would accept your works. Having some material that can be read and studied to determine your abilities is a plus.

Comment: Can you please recommend any less prestigious journals? That would be helpful.

Comment: But I think those journals take forever to review the articles.